# Copy data from int to 2 unsigned chars

Tags: c, int, unsigned-char

How can I copy data from an int (int port1 = 52010) to a pair of unsigned chars (`unsigned char port2[2]`? I don't know how to deal with the division.

Comment: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically use masking and shifting.

```
const unsigned short port = 52010;
uint8_t port2[2];
```

Big-endian:

```
port2[0] = port >> 8;
port2[1] = port & 255;
```

little-endian:

```
port2[0] = port & 255;
port2[1] = port >> 8;
```

For things like port numbers as used in IP networking, you typically always go to the so-called "network byte order" (aka "big-endian"), and there's a special macro for doing this:

```
const unsigned short port_n = ntohs(port);
```

Note that this keeps the port number as a `unsigned short`, while swapping the bytes if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
    port2[0] = port1 >> 8;
    port2[1] = port1 & 0x00FF;
```

or in reverse order depending on endianness

Comment: Well, completely true @unwind, fixed.